# Can't change my array, because I've got Scope Problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I don't know why but I have some problems with my Dashboard.
So basically I want to create some fancy Donut Charts.
For that I've prepared a dataset-Array where I put my numbers in. All that works.
But when I get my data from the database I want to change the array, to update the Chart.
This is where I have problems.

So my data() looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    disturbances_category_0: [],
    disturbances_category_1: [],
    disturbances_category_2: [],
    disturbances_category_3: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [20, 20, 10, 50], //HERE I HAVE TO CHANGE THE NUMBERS <-------------
        backgroundColor: ["#A40000", "#580000", "#EC4A3B", "#179C7D"],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#ff1a1a", "#b30000", "#f4948b", "#66bfac"]
      }
    ],
    labels: ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Cherry"],
    option: {}
  };
},
```

And then there is my created()-Block, where I use Axios + Sequelize and Feathers to get my data:

```
created() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3030/disruptions/', {
    params: {
      DisruptionCategory: 0
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    this.disturbances_category_0 = response.data.data; //HERE IS THE COMPLETE ARRAY 
    this.datasets[0].data[0] = this.disturbances_category_0.length; //HERE I WANT TO SET THE LENGTH
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.data);
  });

  //imagine that for the other fruits as well...
  console.log(this.datasets[0].data[0]);
}
```

If I test this script I always get "20" as printout.
I don't know why it doesn't change the datasets.data-Array ... I also tried out to use Array.push but... nothing happened..

I'm sure I forgot something obvious...

Comment: Which chart plugin are you using? I think the data is updating but you need to refresh the chart to reflect the new data.

Comment: The `axios.get()` call is **asynchronous**, and the code in the `.then()` callback will not run until the HTTP request completes.

Comment: So many posts about promises and async...

Comment: I am using vue-chartjs (https://vue-chartjs.org/). But lets focus first on the fact, that I can't change the array. So thats basic javascript only. I don't know why. And thats absolutely independent from the chart aspect...

Comment: Are you asking, why in your console.log that `this.datasets[0].data[0]` is still returning `20`? It is because the console log likely happened long before your then block executed. It's initial value is an array of four integers before you overwrite it with a length. Try making the `created` function async and await the axios promise chain to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the console log likely happened long before your then block executed. Its initial value is an array of four integers before you overwrite it with a length. Try making the created function async and await the axios promise chain to resolve.

```
async function created() {
  await axios.get('http://localhost:3030/disruptions/', { // await the resolve
    params: {
      DisruptionCategory: 0
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    this.disturbances_category_0 = response.data.data; //HERE IS THE COMPLETE ARRAY 
    this.datasets[0].data[0] = this.disturbances_category_0.length; //HERE I WANT TO SET THE LENGTH
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.data);
  });

  //imagine that for the other fruits as well...
  console.log(this.datasets[0].data[0]); // now this should be updated
}
```

Comment: But I recommend just using "async created()", that worked for me

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure of your exact code structure and where that function lived. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(this.datasets[0].data[0]);
```

The above will run before the response to your request has been handled since it is asynchronous. Your code will just keep executing while the .then() part will execute on another thread once you get a response from the server.

Comment: It also isnt object oriented but at the same time it tries to be. I just didn't know how else to explain what happens.